# Can we call someone who teaches at a university a "teacher"?

Tags: grammar, formal-language

For example, like someone who is teaching people at a university. Is he still called a "teacher" or not?

Comment: Yes, we can. Such a person can be called many things: *teacher*, *professor*, *instructor*, *lecturer*. It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Instead of closing as “lacking details”, I closed as a (close) duplicate. If you browse our site, you might find other related posts. Please see [the Contributor’s Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for more tips and examples.